# Delay loading image before appending content

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I am using the window.scroll function to append new contents when I scroll to end of page. At the same time, the loading spinner image appears at the center but hardly noticed. What I would like to accomplish is when I scroll to bottom of page, the loading image spinner should first appear at the end of last content and delay for 10secs before it slowly appends (fadein) new contents before hiding.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $('#loader').delay(1000).show(0);
    $.getJSON("http://howtodeployit.com/?json=recentstories", function(data) {

    //Set variable for currentPostcount, desiredPosts

    newposts = data.posts.slice(currentPostcount, currentPostcount + desiredPosts);
    $.each(newposts, function(key, val) {
        //Append new contents
        $("#postlist").listview().listview('refresh');
        $('#loader').hide();
        });
    });
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's good way to also slow or delay the appending of contents and not just to `.fadeIn()` then `.fadeOut()` the loader. You can do so by placing your appends on `setTimeout()`:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
       $('#loader').fadeIn(2000);
       $.getJSON("http://howtodeployit.com/?json=recentstories", function(data) {

         newposts = data.posts.slice(currentPostcount, currentPostcount + desiredPosts);

         setTimeout(function(){
            $.each(newposts, function(key, val) {
              //Append new contents
              $("#postlist").listview().listview('refresh');
            });
         },2000);

         $('#loader').fadeOut(2000);
       });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
$('#loader').fadein(10000);
```

something like this should do the work

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $('#loader').fadeIn(5000);
    $.getJSON("http://howtodeployit.com/?json=recentstories", function(data) {

    //Set variable for currentPostcount, desiredPosts

    newposts = data.posts.slice(currentPostcount, currentPostcount + desiredPosts);
    $.each(newposts, function(key, val) {
        //Append new contents
        $("#postlist").listview().listview('refresh');
        });
        $('#loader').fadeOut(5000);
    });
}});
```

Comment: NOP, Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fadein'

Comment: Are you using jqeury with it or not?

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you referring to JQuery JS v1.9.1, if so Yes

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
$('#loader').hide();
}, 10000);

Comment: I'm sorry
try this
$('#loader').fadeIn(10000);

Comment: it's case-sensitive it's not really the same

Comment: It seems to work as expected but the loader never fades out after last content is appended

Comment: try to make it fadeOut instead of fadeIn for the #loader

Comment: Done all that, no luck. The only thing noticed is where I placed the image div in html. it shows on page refresh. I will remove it from html body and insert it in the JS code directly

Comment: unless if your loader position is fixed and you could make it in the middle of the page

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#loader').fadeIn(1000);
```

Notice that it's `fadeIn` (case-sensitive)

Or use `$('#loader').show();` and `fadeOut` at the end (depending on your need):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $('#loader').show();
    $.getJSON("http://howtodeployit.com/?json=recentstories", function(data) {

    //Set variable for currentPostcount, desiredPosts
    newposts = data.posts.slice(currentPostcount, currentPostcount + desiredPosts);
    $.each(newposts, function(key, val) {
        //Append new contents
        $("#postlist").listview().listview('refresh');

        });
       $('#loader').fadeOut(1000);
    });
}});
```